# updating gitignore file from egit in Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, git

I'm new to git (and egit), and am having some problems with it. The problem I'm seeing now is that every time I'm trying to push or merge, I get DIRTY_TREE errors, for files with .DS_Store and .classpath suffixes. I tryed adding those suffixes to the gitignore file in both the local and shared repository , but it doesn't seem to help - git still looks for these files when trying to do anything. Is there anything special that needs to be done in order to change that file?
I'm using eclipse Juno from Mac, let me know if you need any more details.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you add those files to `.gitignore`, you need also to remove them from the index.

```
git rm --cached afile
git commit -m " remove afile"
```

See "[Eclipse Git plugin - remove file from repo without deleting local](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8311883/6309)" to see how to do it in Egit, without the console (even though the CLI -- command-ilne interface) remains the safest way to do it)

```
Team > Untrack
```

Then and only then the `.gitignore` will be in effect.

Comment: Thanks alot!! I'll give it a try later today :)