# Stop tracking and ignore changes to a file in eGit using Momentics IDE

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, egit, momentics

I'm using egit in Momentics (the eclipse based IDE for developing Blackberry 10 apps).

I want to ignore some file from being tracked witout deleting them locally.
In other posts [(e.g. this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241509/eclipse-git-plugin-remove-file-from-repo-without-deleting-local) I found answers to use "untrack" but this seems not to be available in egit under Momentics (or it has been removed meanwhile).

There is no Untrack at all available.

Here is the context menu from the Project in EGIT perspective
[image: context menu in EGit perspective]

The context menu in C perspective shows even less options 
[image: context menu C perspective]

I'm using:

- Momentics IDE for Blackberry V:2.1 Build 201406041640
- Eclipse Platform V: 4.3.2.v20140221-1852 Build: M20140221-1700
- EGIT V:3.4.1.201406201815-r

Comment: Is there an error in your "Error Log" view?

Comment: There where some erros. I assume they where caused by my mishandling during last push. So I deleted the Error log.
Unfortunately I'm not able to get it back :-(

Answer (score 0):

First: Forget about egit, at least until it becomes more robust and error-free. I have experienced so many time-wasting issues and lack-of-accommodation with that tool, and in fact it has [numerous documented defects](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?bug_file_loc=&bug_file_loc_type=allwordssubstr&bug_id=&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&bugidtype=include&chfieldfrom=&chfieldto=Now&chfieldvalue=&classification=Technology&cmdtype=doit&email1=&email2=&emailtype1=exact&emailtype2=substring&field0-0-0=noop&keywords=&keywords_type=allwords&long_desc=&long_desc_type=allwordssubstr&order=Reuse%20same%20sort%20as%20last%20time&product=EGit&query_format=advanced&short_desc=&short_desc_type=allwordssubstr&status_whiteboard=&status_whiteboard_type=allwordssubstr&type0-0-0=noop&value0-0-0=&votes=).  If you like to use a GUI for git (like I do), use [Git Extensions](http://gitextensions.github.io/) instead.

Second: You're supposed to use an .ignore file to prevent items from being tracked; here are a [few samples](https://github.com/github/gitignore).

Finally: If you need to untrack things that have already been committed, you'll probably need to drop to the command line anyway:  Commit your changes, then in Git Bash type

```
git rm -r --cached "path/to/foo/"
```

Then I think you'll need to commit again.

From a closely-related topic here at stackoverflow:
[Untrack and stop tracking files in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027873/untrack-and-stop-tracking-files-in-git)